# How do I retrieve an element with a specific ID from another webpage?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to retrieve the value of an element with a certain ID from another webpage. I know that to retrieve an element on the same page is:

```
document.getElementById("thingy1");
```

Is there a way to input an address and id, and return a value?

Comment: `document` is always the current web page. You need to use `someOtherDocument.getElementById("thingy1")`, where `someOtherDocument` is produced by loading the other webpage with AJAX.

Comment: Keep in mind that if the other webpage isn't on the same domain, you won't be able to access anything since it would break the same origin policy.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [window.open](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp)

```
var otherWindow = window.open(url);
var otherDocument = otherWindow.document; //<-- access the other document
```

This way you can access the document from another window.

I've never actually done that (getting an element), but i've written information on the other document this way.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery `load()` [supports loading page fragments](http://api.jquery.com/load/#loading-page-fragments), provided the target's on the same domain, or its CORS has been configured accordingly:

```
$('#container').load('http://example.com #content-to-load');
```

Answer (score -1):

By and large, you cannot access the DOM of a page loaded from another domain. This is why:

> In computing, the same-origin policy is an important concept in the
>   web application security model. The policy permits scripts running on
>   pages originating from the same site – a combination of scheme,
>   hostname, and port number – to access each other's DOM with no
>   specific restrictions, **but prevents access to DOM on different sites**.

See SOP: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy